# Passing a function and a prop to another component but getting undefined

Tags: reactjs, undefined, react-props, react-component

This just the rough code trying to make sure data is sending between each component so this is me testing (file: navbar.js)

```
import React from 'react';
import {Nav,} from 'react-bootstrap';
import styles from 'styled-components';
import Layout from './layout';
import Reports from './reports';



const Navbar =() =>{

    function handler(x){
    
        if (x==1){
            return <Reports></Reports>
        }
    }
    return(
    
    <Nav defaultActiveKey="/" className="flex-column" onSelect={(selectedKey) => <Layout page={selectedKey} func={handler}></Layout>}>
        <Nav.Link href="/">Home</Nav.Link>
        <Nav.Link href="/Orders">Orders</Nav.Link>
        <Nav.Link href="/Users">Users</Nav.Link>
        <Nav.Link eventKey='1' href="/Reports">Reports</Nav.Link>
    </Nav>

    )

}

export default Navbar;
```

Now the problem occurs in layout class when trying to access the props (file: layout.js)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Nav, Col , Row, Container} from 'react-bootstrap';
import styles from 'styled-components';
import Navbar from './navbar';



class Layout extends Component{
    
    render(){
        
        return(
            <Container fluid>
                <Row>
                    <Col xs={3}>
                    <Navbar>
                    </Navbar>
                    
                    </Col>
                    <Col>
                        {this.props.func(this.props.page)}
                        column 2
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>

        )
    }

}

export default Layout;
```

what am trying to accomplish is to return the component chosen from the nav by using handler to get eventKey which is stored in selectedKey after a click, currently was trying to do it for the report page.

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: ×
TypeError: this.props.func is not a function
Layout.render

     | ^  22 |     {this.props.func(this.props.page)}
  23 |     colomn 2
  24 | </Col>      so basically the function I called func is not reaching to the layout component neither is the prop named page

Comment: Okay, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render on the basis of selected page values you can do this display logic just get the current path through **window.location.pathname** as href will change your url to that path, and based on path value render the respective component

```
        function handler(){

        const page = window.location.pathname; // this will return current page path

        if (page==="/")
          return (<HomePage/>)
        else if (page === "/Orders")
          return(<Orders/>)
        else if (page === "/Reports")
          return (<Reports/>)
  }
```

Hope this helps!

**Updated:**
Try binding your function to the class like this

```
const Navbar =() =>{
 constructor(props){
 super(props);
 this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
 }
}
```

Comment: this would work if the function was being called but it's saying that func that I passed to layout component isn't a function.   {this.props.func(this.props.page)} @Ibrahim

Comment: Hi Tom! Try binding your handler function in the NavBar to the instance of the class (this)     Code ==>                                                                        constructor(props){   super( props); this.handler =  this.handler.bind(this);   }

Comment: I just figured out that you don't need to bind "arrow functions" to the instance of the class. Strange though

Comment: I converted navbar to a class component did the constructor and made the call in the layout component but its the same undefined no matter what I do my props ain't showing up in the layout component

Comment: <Nav defaultActiveKey="/" className="flex-column" onSelect={(selectedKey) => <Layout func={this.handler} page={selectedKey}></Layout>}>   then in the layout component i do this   {this.props.func(this.props.page)} for the call how does did not work

Comment: thanks for the help i solved the problem I had two instances of the component so I had to just use the first component rather than the second to make an update

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the JSX as children and then use them where you want and why not call the function in the parent component itself?

Try this:

```
const Navbar = () => {

  const handler = (x) => {
    if (x == 1) {
      return <Reports></Reports>
    }
  }
  return (
    <Nav defaultActiveKey="/" className="flex-column" onSelect={(selectedKey) => <Layout >{handler(selectedKey)}</Layout>}>
      <Nav.Link href="/">Home</Nav.Link>
      <Nav.Link href="/Orders">Orders</Nav.Link>
      <Nav.Link href="/Users">Users</Nav.Link>
      <Nav.Link eventKey='1' href="/Reports">Reports</Nav.Link>
    </Nav>

  )
}

class Layout extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Container fluid>
        <Row>
          <Col xs={3}>
            <Navbar>
            </Navbar>
          </Col>
          <Col>
           {this.props.children}
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: {this.props.children} still says undefined when logged to the console

Comment: @TroySmith make sure that `handler(selectedKey)` is returning some JSX.

Comment: thanks for the help i solved the problem I had two instances of the component so I had to just use the first component rather than the second to make an update